# Assembler. Распознавание эмуляции среды

Tags: ассемблер

Некоторые программы(например, антивирусные) эмулируют изолированную среду для PE файлов. Как можно при помощи Assembler распознать такую среду? Идеально было бы кусок кода, но буду вполне доволен и описанием алгоритма. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможно по каким-нибудь регистрам, например.

Comment: Выполнить какую то asm команду которую среда не осилит.

Comment: не соглашусь, есть просто ассемблер программы, которые определяют виртуальная машина это или нет. Вот мне можно сказать это и надо. Хотя на виртуалке все работает.

Comment: А ассемблер программы состоят не из ассемблер команд? ;-)

Comment: ну так как видишь виртуалки выполняют ассемблер команды, следовательно твой совет неверен )

Comment: Подобная задача определенно может быть решена путем дерганья API операционной системы. Все вызовы непроэмулировать. Второй подход - получение характеристик железа/софта. И оба подхода можно реализовать без асма.

Comment: @СемёнСавенко не все команды выполняются корректно. Та же VMWare, например, на cpuid выдает реальные характеристики камня, а не то что указано в настройках виртуалки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то по идее тут подход должен быть комплексным. Универсальным способо определить эмулятор (хотя точнее говорить, это все-таки некая виртуалка), думаю, нельзя. Но при этом вряд ли какие-то программы (антивирусы) будут использовать полностью самостоятельно написанну VM, а это значит, что они используют что-то готовое. Поэтому можно попробовать взять некие типовые способы определения каждой виртуалки поотдельности и последовательно выполнять все проверки

Если говорить про то, какими способами это можно делать, то тут разные варианты: ключи регистра, какие-то особые драйвера, команды, железо и т.д.

Примеры (возможно немного устаревшие) можете посмотреть в статье (даже английский знать не обязательно, чтобы скопипастить): https://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Virtual_Machine_Threats.pdf

Comment: Некоторые антивирусы определенно используют собственные эмуляторы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов согласен. Ну вот с этими некоторыми антивирусами надо разбираться отдельно, т.к. некоего "универсального" способа найти не получится.